# Array becomes an Integer after applying unshift on it

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an Object like this:

```
{
  "index": 0,
  "name": "b1a042ff6-0c75-4af2-a9da-1a16f333baee_p0",
  "category": "others",
  "rawUrl": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/vrcam-dev-5a815.appspot.com/o/5ab4f2a0-88e9-4bf5-86b5-61b528be707f/panoramas/panorama_XTsagLoxbA.png?alt=media&token=68ef261e-0c5e-4bf0-aebc-ab845fcec01a",
  "isTopLogo": false,
  "origin": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/vrcam-dev-5a815.appspot.com/o/5ab4f2a0-88e9-4bf5-86b5-61b528be707f/panoramas/panorama_XTsagLoxbA.png?alt=media&token=68ef261e-0c5e-4bf0-aebc-ab845fcec01a",
  "position": {
    "x": 0,
    "y": 0
  },
  "panoramaRotation": {
    "x": 0,
    "y": 0,
    "z": 0
  }
}
```

Which I want to `unshift` to an Array (it's cloned version) like this:

```
[{
  "adjustedRawUrl": "",
  "category": "others",
  "createdAt": 1514432540000,
  "cubemapReady": false,
  "desktopUrl": "https://im.ages.io/BGOLielt?cors&w=513",
  "floorplanRotation": 0,
  "index": 0,
  "is720": false,
  "isTopLogo": false,
  "mobileUrl": "https://im.ages.io/BGOLielt?cors&w=4096",
  "name": "b1a042ff6-0c75-4af2-a9da-1a16f333baee_p0",
  "objectId": "3c312986-0ef1-42fc-9068-46fc13a04b8f",
  "panoramaRotation": {
    "x": 0,
    "y": 0,
    "z": 0
  },
  "position": {
    "x": 0,
    "y": 0
  },
  "rawUrl": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/vrcam-dev-5a815.appspot.com/o/5ab4f2a0-88e9-4bf5-86b5-61b528be707f/panoramas/panorama_lPea0mIc6H.png?alt=media&token=9e1494ff-2525-42a6-a058-12c26560349a",
  "stereoUrl": "",
  "thumbnail": "https://im.ages.io/BGOLielt?cors&w=400",
  "updatedAt": 1514432619000
}, {
  "adjustedRawUrl": "",
  "category": "others",
  "createdAt": 1514432231000,
  "cubemapReady": false,
  "desktopUrl": "https://im.ages.io/FK9uiel2?cors&w=251",
  "floorplanRotation": 0,
  "index": 1,
  "is720": false,
  "isTopLogo": false,
  "mobileUrl": "https://im.ages.io/FK9uiel2?cors&w=4096",
  "name": "b1a042ff6-0c75-4af2-a9da-1a16f333baee_p0",
  "objectId": "08e9197c-ab27-48d8-a48d-b33452fcfd11",
  "panoramaRotation": {
    "x": 0,
    "y": 0,
    "z": 0
  },
  "position": {
    "x": 0,
    "y": 0
  },
  "rawUrl": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/vrcam-dev-5a815.appspot.com/o/5ab4f2a0-88e9-4bf5-86b5-61b528be707f/panoramas/panorama_pMUnnhYmpH.png?alt=media&token=e422e4f1-389b-43b7-927b-022b31e37d61",
  "stereoUrl": "",
  "thumbnail": "https://im.ages.io/FK9uiel2?cors&w=400",
  "updatedAt": 1514432619000
}]
```

This is how I'm doing it:

```
const newClonedArray = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(array)).unshift(object)
```

To my shock the result wasn't an Array but an Integer: `3`.

Why is this? And how to fix it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`array.unshift()` returns `length` of the modified array. It does not create a new array instead modifies the existing array. Thus you do not need to use any assignment here.

```js
var object ={
  "index": 0,
  "name": "b1a042ff6-0c75-4af2-a9da-1a16f333baee_p0",
  "category": "others",
  "rawUrl": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/vrcam-dev-5a815.appspot.com/o/5ab4f2a0-88e9-4bf5-86b5-61b528be707f/panoramas/panorama_XTsagLoxbA.png?alt=media&token=68ef261e-0c5e-4bf0-aebc-ab845fcec01a",
  "isTopLogo": false,
  "origin": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/vrcam-dev-5a815.appspot.com/o/5ab4f2a0-88e9-4bf5-86b5-61b528be707f/panoramas/panorama_XTsagLoxbA.png?alt=media&token=68ef261e-0c5e-4bf0-aebc-ab845fcec01a",
  "position": {
    "x": 0,
    "y": 0
  },
  "panoramaRotation": {
    "x": 0,
    "y": 0,
    "z": 0
  }
}

var array = [];

array.unshift(object);

console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 1):

The [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift) explain

> The `unshift()` method adds one or more elements to the beginning of an array and **returns the new length of the array**.

Maybe instead of assigning the result of `unshift`, do

```
const newClonedArray = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(array));
newClonedArray.unshift(object);
```